# No changes after compiling Silverlight project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I am confused. I am adding changes to the Silverlight project and it compiles if there is no any errors. But after I launch the project I can't see any changes. What is going on?

Comment: What browser are you checking it in?

Comment: Google Chrome. And it worked earlier without any problems.

Comment: It may be your cache. Try pressing `Ctrl + F5`

Comment: It doesn't help. Very strange.

Comment: And if you switch browsers? Say, to IE?

Comment: I need to do something bad with Google Chrome.

Comment: But the problem is open. What is the reason Google chrome doesn't works and how it can be resolved?

Comment: Clear chrome's cache ? Ctrl+Shift+Del to bring up the menu

Comment: On occasion I have been known to be building a VS project in Debug, but running it from Release and cursing as to why my changes haven't shown up.  I'm not familiar with Silverlight projects so I am not sure if this could be a contributing factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around the caching problem you can add a parameter to the xap file in the source attribute of your aspx page.

Instead of just writing

```
<param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApp.xap"/>
```

you can use something like this:

```
<param name="source" value="<%= String.Format("ClientBin/SilverlightApp.xap?ver={0}", (new System.IO.FileInfo("ClientBin/SilverlightApp.xap")).CreationTime.Ticks.ToString()) %>"/>
```

That way, every time the xap file is compiled again, the browser will see a new parameter and should load the correct file.

Comment: had a similar problem, just tried it and it works (with chrome)

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. When I compile the project I see just empty page.

Comment: @Peter17 Please post the source of the aspx page (or at least the part where the Silverlight app is defined).